# Display all possible combinations of a logical expression

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing a program to display all possible combinations of a logical expression.

```
Example1: (A and (B or C))
Output:
A and B
A and C

Example2: ((A or B) and (C or D))
Output:
A and C
A and D
B and C
B and D
```

The only solution which I could think of is to build an infix binary tree and then traverse to get the outputs. Also in that case I'm not sure how to maintain the order. Or is there a simpler solution than that?

Comment: This is exactly like expanding mathematical expressions if you replace `AND` with `*` and `OR` with `+`. So you might wan to look into how those are done.

Comment: A [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) could fit nicely here.

Comment: You can build an expression tree and explore all the possible combinations. Note: you might need `!A and !B`

Comment: I guess I am able to get a solution using JavaScript. It goes into a recursion.

Comment: Could just throw all your input at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LogicalExpand%5BA+%26%26+(B+%7C%7C+C)%5D)